# if-statement null-check not working in Kotlin, why?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, null-check

As shown in below, in debug, if-statement with null-check is entered even though the variable "result" is null.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWyNL.png)
Blue line is the line next to be executed. So if-has been entered.

This is how "result" is initialized:
var result: Double? = null

"result" is updated in a TextField composables onValueChange function and set to null in onValueChange, **before** the if-statement with nullcheck. Something like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njuFV.png)

I can't understand why the if-statements null-check doesn't work.

Any clues anyone?

The if-statement is entered if "result" is not null also.

Comment: Please paste text not images.  Here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kotlin is null safe language** so basically what happens in your code is that lets say in the moment **T0** we have `result != Null` but in the moment **T1** when inside of the If block is going to be executed another function or line of code in another thread or something has changed `result = null` then what happens even though the if condition has been passed successfully now the result is `null` and will cause an error.

Kotlin introduced a solution with the `Let` keyword so basically instead of having:

```
If(result != Null){
//Do something
}
```

You have to use:

```
result?.let{nonNullResult->
//Do something with this nonNullResult
}
```

As you can see when you use the `let` keyword what happens is kotlin takes a **copy** of that variable at that specific time when the line is executed if the copy is **null** the inside block of `let` will not be executed else if the copy is **not null** then the `Let` block will be executed with that **non null copy**.

Comment: Ok, but in all moments upp to the if-statement with the null-check the result has been null. result gets set at the OnClick function of a button. So it is null always until that button is clicked.

Thank you for the alternative solution!

How can i know when it is possible to use if(result != null) and when not? This method ( if(result != null) )is tought in Googles Kotlin courses.

Comment: @furco If you want my opinion and my experience especially with kotlin+compose always use Let keyword don't use if statement.

Comment: And if you find the answer helpful pls mark it as correct

Comment: It is wierd that Google itself teaches if(result != null) in their own Kotlin course:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-nullability?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-2-pathway-1%3Fauthuser%3D1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-nullability#2

Am i missunderstanding what they mean maybe?